# Does anyone actually have the facebook graph insights api working today?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I went through all the oauth setup, authorized my app, got a token, but when I try to pull insights data for any page, the values are all zeros, see [this thread](http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?pid=239754#p239754), others are having same problem.

I'm just wondering if its a code problem or a problem with facebook?

If you have it working, can you share some sample code? (any language is fine)

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but if a bunch of people suddenly start having this issue it seems to me that it's a Facebook-side problem and not from your end. I suggest to contact Facebook support.

Comment: The docs are so messy these days, it wouldn't surprise me if everyone was just making the same mistake.

Comment: also, how do you contact facebook support? I thought their forums were the only thing they had, and this topic has been out there for a while with no answer.

Comment: I remember guessing their email address way back when. support@facebook.com, info@facebook.com :)